# define function templated class outside of template

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

It's kind of hard to explain, but basically, I want to do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class some{
    int hello();
};

//The method needs to be defined outside of the template class declaration and be able to use T defined in the template
int some::hello(){
    T* other = new T;
    T->doSomething();
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see a question anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, edited it.

Comment: You should use `template <typename T> int some<T>::hello(){ ...`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you know if there's a dupe for this? Feels like there must be, but I can only find out-of-line definitions of member templates.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ah, perfect, thanks :)

Comment: @cigien I just picked one. Most of the relevant questions ask about separation in header and source files unfortunately. Feel free to add further ones if you find them.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're right, the current target is a little broader. Certainly enough to answer the OP though. I wonder if this is just too simple and so there's no exact dupe? :p

Comment: @cigien Not necessarily _simple_ to get the syntax correctly. I remember too failing the first attempt often when implementing code fast. But if you know how to interpret the compiler errors, it's easy to fix with a 2nd try ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're right, I think I was overcomplicating it a bit in my head. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @V0_1D Always glad to help.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See the dupe target I added, it's beautiful :) Why isn't there one where the member function is *not* a template :(

Comment: I already though this must be dupe, but I couldn't find it. Mostly because I had trouble formulating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
template <typename T>
class some{
    int hello();
};

//The method needs to be defined outside of the template class declaration and be able to use T defined in the template
template<typename T>
int some<T>::hello(){
    T* other = new T;
    other->doSomething();
}
```